# MySQL IF Case Exsists check if user is attached

Tags: mysql, sql

hi I need users to be able to register access to cases from a cases table by entering a unique case code. the database needs to check if the case code exists and if it does use its id to see if the user is already registered to it

```
cases
        +----+-----------+-------------+
        | id | case_code |  case_name  |
        +----+-----------+-------------+
        |  1 | THEC12C   | Test Case 1 |
        |  2 | ABCD23A   | Test Case 2 |
        +----+-----------+-------------+

case_creditors
        +----+---------+-------------+
        | id | case_id | creditor_id |
        +----+---------+-------------+
        |  1 |       1 |           3 |
        |  2 |       2 |           1 |
        +----+---------+-------------+
```

So if creditor 1 tries to add THEC12C it would add a record to case users

```
case_creditors
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | case_id | creditor_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 |           3 |
|  2 |       2 |           1 |
|  3 |       1 |           1 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

if they try to add the same case again it will return a row so I can tell php this user is already registered with this case

i know i can use two queries to accomplish this
1) does the case code exist in cases table - true / False
2) if true is there a record in case_creditors  - true / false
3} if true "already registered if false add recored of case_id and creditor_id to case_creditors"

Comment: So what is your question? Are you looking for the SQL to do the query, or for more/different ideas on how to do the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it completely differently.

1. Create a single [unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on `case_id` and `creditor_id` fields in the `case_creditors` table. This would prevent duplicate records from being inserted.
2. Use the following `insert ... select ... query to insert data into`case_creditors` table.

If it returns with duplicate key error, then case has already been assigned to creditor. If affected row is 0, then `case_code` does not exists. If affected rows is 1, then case is assigned to creditor:

```
insert into case_creditors (case_id, creditor_id)
select id, ... from cases where case_code='...'
```

Substitute the creditor id in place of the first `...`, and the case code in place of the 2nd `...`.

Comment: cheers Shadow didn't think of that :) I should have spent a little more time in the planning stage but all good now